# Print SQL generated by SQLObject

Tags: python, sqlobject

```py
from sqlobject import *

class Data(SQLObject):
    ts = TimeCol()
    val = FloatCol()

Data.select().count()
```

Fails with:

```
AttributeError: No connection has been defined for this thread or process
```

How do I get the SQL which would be generated, without declaring a connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible for two reasons. 1st, `.count()` not only generates a query, it also executes it, so not only it requires a connection, it also requires a database and a populated table. 2nd, different queries could be generated for different backends (esp. in the area of quoting strings) so a connection is required to render a query object to a string.

To generate a query string with accumulator function you need to repeat [the code that generates the query](http://sqlobject.org/_modules/sqlobject/dbconnection.html#DBAPI.accumulateSelect). So the full solution for your question is

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python

from sqlobject import *

__connection__ = "sqlite:/:memory:?debug=1"

class Data(SQLObject):
    ts = TimeCol()
    val = FloatCol()

print(Data.select().queryForSelect().newItems("COUNT(*)"))
```